# RMarkdown and tinytex: unable to print to PDF

Tags: r, pdf, r-markdown, tinytex

I have installed tinytex into RStudio, and yet when I attempt tp knit to PDF, I get the following error message:

> ! Package pdftex.def Error: File `file:///C:/Users/benja/Documents/R/Images/Doc
> 1.png' not found: using draft setting.

> Error: LaTeX failed to compile Speedy-Success.tex. See https://yihui.org/tinytex/r/#debugging for debugging tips. See Speedy-Success.log for more info.
> Execution halted

> No LaTeX installation detected (LaTeX is required to create PDF output). You should install a LaTeX distribution for your platform: https://www.latex-project.org/get/

> If you are not sure, you may install TinyTeX in R: tinytex::install_tinytex()

> Otherwise consider MiKTeX on Windows - http://miktex.org

> MacTeX on macOS - https://tug.org/mactex/
> (NOTE: Download with Safari rather than Chrome *strongly* recommended)

> Linux: Use system package manager

I have tried uninstalling tinytext and reinstalling it; no dice.  I have made certain tinytext is loaded; nothing.  Any suggestions are very welcome.  Thank you.

Comment: What about a LaTeX  installation as mentioned in the error message.  Are you sure that's installed as well?

Comment: Limey:  I had thought that LaTeX was installed as part of tinytex.  Am I mistaken?  Is there another installation package I can download?

Comment: Try: `install.packages('tinytex')`
`tinytex::install_tinytex()`